# declarative resource based requirement authorization not working with API Controller

Tags: api, asp.net-core, declarative-authorization, resource-based-authorization

I am trying setup an authoriztion policy that I can use to decorate actions in API Controllers in .net core 3.1. I have been following these examples :
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-3.1

If i have an API action decorated like below my code does not hit the handlerequirementAsync method of the handler and I get a 403 Forbidden response from swagger. If i remove the document model from the handler/requirement it does work. Am I doing something wrong or is this not supported for api requests?

here is the other relevant code :

```
    public class DocumentAuthorizationHandler : 
    AuthorizationHandler<SameAuthorRequirement, Document>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   SameAuthorRequirement requirement,
                                                   Document resource)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity?.Name == resource.Author)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class SameAuthorRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }


[Authorize(Policy = "EditPolicy")]
public async Task<FileResult> RetreiveFile([FromRoute]Document model)


 {
 }

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EditPolicy", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new SameAuthorRequirement()));
});

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, DocumentAuthorizationHandler>();
```

Comment: What's your configuration in `Startup.cs` ? If you want the community to review ande debug the code , please show the relevant code that can reproduce the issue . This github issue https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/14944  may be helpful,you could refer to.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the feedback. my code mirrors the resource based authorization example in the Microsoft documentation in the link exactly. Ill past the code into the question for clarity

Answer (score 0):

You should have to inject `IAuthorizationService` in the controller constructor

```
public class AbcController : Controller
{
   private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;

   public AbcController(IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
   {
      _authorizationService = authorizationService;
   } 
   // No need to add this [Authorize(Policy = "EditPolicy")]
   public async Task<FileResult> RetreiveFile([FromRoute]Document model)
   {
      //add this below line which shall call the handler
       var authorizationResult = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, model, "EditPolicy"); 
   }
```